# Serialize a bool into a single bit in c++ and unserialize into boolean in java

Tags: java, c++, serialization, deserialization

I have two separate applications, one written in java and the other written in C++, that communicate with each other via socket. I'm trying to meet a bandwidth requirement by reducing the number of bytes in my data structure. Part of my solution is to send variables that are stored in the C++ application as bools as a single bit, but I'm not sure how to put a single 1 or 0 into my char* buffer. I realize that a char has to be a full byte, but I have many bools that could be passed over the socket as 1's and 0's in the same bytes. How can I accomplish this in C++?

On the other side of things, how would I go about parsing the bytes with 1's and 0's representing my bools into Booleans in the java application? I'm currently using a ByteBuffer in my java application. Is this compatible with what I want to do? If so, how can I accomplish this, and if not, what is an alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a char to represent 8 bools, you can then perform a BITWISE AND (&) on your character and a control mask to determine which bits were flipped.

For example:  I have a char eightBools = 'A'; //A is ascii 65 = 01000001b
If I want to check the least significant column, I can bitwise AND eightBools with 00000001.

The result of

```
    010000001 //char 'a'
  & 000000001 //ascii [start-of-heading], or integer 1
 is 000000001. //equals 1.  You know this bit is flipped.
```

You now know that the lowest order bit is flipped.  If, instead, you want to see if the second MOST significant bit is flipped, you can and it with that particular bit.

```
   010000001 //char 'a' or int 65
 & 010000000 //char '@' or int 64
is 010000000 // equals 64.  Now you know this bit is flipped.
```

Using this method, you can utilize a character as an array of 8 bools.

Comment: How can I efficiently determine what character represents my 8 bools?

Comment: @ping You don't necessarily have to.  You can use bitshift operations to pack your characters!  So long as you shift the bits into the char in the same order every time, you can shift them back out in the reverse order.